# How to parse VirtualMachinePaged object using Azure SDK for Python?

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to get list of VMs in a Resource Group using Azure SDK for Python. I configured my Visual Studio code with all the required Azure Tools. I created a function and used below code to get List of VMs.

```
import os
import random
import string

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient

def main():

    SUBSCRIPTION_ID = os.environ.get("SUBSCRIPTION_ID", None)
    GROUP_NAME = "testgroupx"
    VIRTUAL_MACHINE_NAME = "virtualmachinex"
    SUBNET_NAME = "subnetx"
    INTERFACE_NAME = "interfacex"
    NETWORK_NAME = "networknamex"
    VIRTUAL_MACHINE_EXTENSION_NAME = "virtualmachineextensionx"

resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
        subscription_id=SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    )
    network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
        subscription_id=SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    )
    compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
        subscription_id=SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    )

vm = compute_client .virtual_machines.list(
        'RGName'
    )

print("Get virtual machine:\n{}", vm)
```

When I see the logs, I see below as the print response.

```
<azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_12_01.models._paged_models.VirtualMachinePaged object at 0x0000024584F92EC8>
```

I am really trying to get the actual object, I am not sure how can I parse it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Since it returns a collection you need to use Use for loop , You can do something like this

```
for vm in compute_client .virtual_machines.list('RGName'):
  print("\tVM: {}".format(vm.name))
```

Comment: I get the following error by doing that.

`Executed 'Functions.VMStopScheduler' (Failed, Id=3f9529b4-53a4-4c55-8698-63cbf2874564)
[6/5/2020 2:33:48 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.VMStopScheduler. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
Exception: AttributeError: 'DefaultAzureCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate?tabs=cmd seems to be an issue with authentication

Comment: thanks for the link. If anybody needs help. Check below.
1. Make sure you have Owner role for your user
2. Run this command `az ad sp create-for-rbac --sdk-auth` which gives your client permission to access azure resources.
3. Use the generated JSON in python codelike this `compute_client = get_client_from_json_dict(ComputeManagementClient, config_dict)`
4. config_dict is a JSON dict from point 2

Answer (score -1):

`VirtualMachinePaged` contains a collection of an object of type `VirtualMachine`. You can see the source code of that class here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/compute/azure-mgmt-compute/azure/mgmt/compute/v2019_12_01/models/_models.py.

From this link, here're the list of attributes:

```
{
    'id': {'key': 'id', 'type': 'str'},
    'name': {'key': 'name', 'type': 'str'},
    'type': {'key': 'type', 'type': 'str'},
    'location': {'key': 'location', 'type': 'str'},
    'tags': {'key': 'tags', 'type': '{str}'},
    'plan': {'key': 'plan', 'type': 'Plan'},
    'hardware_profile': {'key': 'properties.hardwareProfile', 'type': 'HardwareProfile'},
    'storage_profile': {'key': 'properties.storageProfile', 'type': 'StorageProfile'},
    'additional_capabilities': {'key': 'properties.additionalCapabilities', 'type': 'AdditionalCapabilities'},
    'os_profile': {'key': 'properties.osProfile', 'type': 'OSProfile'},
    'network_profile': {'key': 'properties.networkProfile', 'type': 'NetworkProfile'},
    'diagnostics_profile': {'key': 'properties.diagnosticsProfile', 'type': 'DiagnosticsProfile'},
    'availability_set': {'key': 'properties.availabilitySet', 'type': 'SubResource'},
    'virtual_machine_scale_set': {'key': 'properties.virtualMachineScaleSet', 'type': 'SubResource'},
    'proximity_placement_group': {'key': 'properties.proximityPlacementGroup', 'type': 'SubResource'},
    'priority': {'key': 'properties.priority', 'type': 'str'},
    'eviction_policy': {'key': 'properties.evictionPolicy', 'type': 'str'},
    'billing_profile': {'key': 'properties.billingProfile', 'type': 'BillingProfile'},
    'host': {'key': 'properties.host', 'type': 'SubResource'},
    'provisioning_state': {'key': 'properties.provisioningState', 'type': 'str'},
    'instance_view': {'key': 'properties.instanceView', 'type': 'VirtualMachineInstanceView'},
    'license_type': {'key': 'properties.licenseType', 'type': 'str'},
    'vm_id': {'key': 'properties.vmId', 'type': 'str'},
    'resources': {'key': 'resources', 'type': '[VirtualMachineExtension]'},
    'identity': {'key': 'identity', 'type': 'VirtualMachineIdentity'},
    'zones': {'key': 'zones', 'type': '[str]'},
}
```

For Python 3, the code can be found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/compute/azure-mgmt-compute/azure/mgmt/compute/v2019_12_01/models/_models_py3.py.